# Не понимаю, почему фактически идентичный код работает по разному

Tags: java, многопоточность, android-threads

Вот именно отрывок который меня выбешивает:

```
AnalJ anal2 = new AnalJ();
        Thread anal3 = new Thread(anal2);
        anal3.start();
        new AnalG().start();
        new Thread().start(anal2);
```

Для меня является не понятным, чем отличается **Thread anal3 = new Thread(anal2);** от  **new Thread().start(anal2);**
По факту это же одно и то же?

Вот картинка полного кода[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего у класса Thread нет метода start с аргументами (или с аргументом типа Thread), что делает ваш вопрос странным - код абсолютно не идентичен и не работает, потому что и не может работать

Comment: Однако интересные названия у вас классов. Полный код надо прикладывать, а не фотографии ваших "Аналов"

Comment: я давно заметил, как код назовёшь, через то он и работать будет :)))

Answer (score 1):

У `Thread` нет метода `start` с указанием `Runnable` для запуска. Либо надо подавать `Runnable` в конструктор (как у вас сделано для первого варианта). Либо делать наследование класса `Thread` с переопределением `run`, в котором и писать нужный код.

Comment: спасибо большое